# How to find all possible groups of four different values(integers)

Tags: permutations, combinations

I have four values :50,100,500,1000.

I want to know many groups could be made with this combinations values.

50,100,500,1000   here it would be count as 1+1+1+1

50,50,50,100      count= 3+1

50,50,100,500     count = 2+1+1

50,50,50,50       count = 4

50,100,50,500     count = 2+1+1

50,100,500,50     count = 2+1+1

and many more

how many more groups could be done .Can they be found with permutations or combinations if I want to know groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let there be a 50's, b 100's, c 500's and d 1000's.

a + b + c + d = 4, where a, b, c and d are non-negative integers.

Assume that the 4 are like 4 balls (0) and there are 3 barriers (!) that separate the balls. i.e.

> 0!00!0!

Then, the 4 variables would be:

> (a 0's) ! (b 0's) ! (c 0's) ! (d 0's)

So we are finding the number of possibilities of mixing up 4 0's and 3 !'s.

So the answer is $\frac{7!}{3!\cdot4!}$ = $7\choose{4}$ = 210